# I want my multihopOscilloscope to send data through radio and Serial port as well

Tags: tinyos, nesc

I am trying to modify the multihop Oscilloscope program so that the sink node is able to send data both to UART and radio medium as well. As far as researched, I found out that the same hardware is used for sending packets via UART and radio too.
In this case, how do I modify my code so that I can send data to UART or radio based on a condition I receive. Here in the sample prorgram, I send data via radio on every 10 packets received.

The receive module for my sink node is:

```
event message_t*  Receive.receive(message_t* msg, void *payload, uint8_t len) {
oscilloscope_t* in = (oscilloscope_t*)payload;
  counter++;
am_addr_t rec = call AMPacket.source(msg);

oscilloscope_t* out;
counter++;
    call Leds.led0On();
if (uartbusy == FALSE) {
  out = (oscilloscope_t*)call SerialSend.getPayload(&uartbuf, sizeof(oscilloscope_t));
  if (len != sizeof(oscilloscope_t) || out == NULL) {
return msg;
  }
  else {
memcpy(out, in, sizeof(oscilloscope_t));
  }
  uartlen = sizeof(oscilloscope_t);
  post uartSendTask();
} else {
  message_t *newmsg = call UARTMessagePool.get();
  if (newmsg == NULL) {
    report_problem();
    return msg;
  }

  //Serial port busy, so enqueue.
  out = (oscilloscope_t*)call SerialSend.getPayload(newmsg, sizeof(oscilloscope_t));
  if (out == NULL) {
return msg;
  }
  memcpy(out, in, sizeof(oscilloscope_t));

  if (call UARTQueue.enqueue(newmsg) != SUCCESS) {

    call UARTMessagePool.put(newmsg);
    fatal_problem();
    return msg;
  }
}
if(counter % 10 == 0){  
oscilloscope_t* btrpkt = (oscilloscope_t*)(call Packet.getPayload(&pkt, sizeof(oscilloscope_t)));
call Leds.led1On();
if (call AMSend.send(rec, &pkt, sizeof(oscilloscope_t)) == SUCCESS) {
call Leds.led0On();
    sendbusy = TRUE;
  }
}
return msg;

}
```

Once the data sends back to the node from where it received the packet , it is unable to process it through UART again. Could anyone help me how could I solve my problem?

Comment: 1. You don't put any payload into `btrpkt`.
2. You don't check `sendbusy` before trying to send.
3. How do you instantiate a component wired to `AMSend`? It should have the same id (`AM_OSCILLOSCOPE` according to https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/blob/master/apps/MultihopOscilloscopeLqi/MultihopOscilloscopeAppC.nc) if you want your message to be processed by the same code on the receiver's side.
4. I don't really understand what you mean by writing that the same hardware is used for UART and radio. Which platform?

Comment: Maral, I am using mica platform for the node. I am not checking sendbusy flag just as to shorten my code. 
Instantatin the AMSend in  MultihopOscilloscopeAppC.nc file 
`components new AMSenderC(DEFAULT_INTERVAL) as RadioSend;`
`MultihopOscilloscopeC.AMSend -> RadioSend;`
and using this in MultihopOscilloscopeC.nc 
All I want is my sink node should be able to process data to Serial port if the flag is FALSE or send it back to the node from where it received the packete if the flag is TRUE. Here,I'm using (counter %10 == 0) to be the flag for simplifying.  Could you help me more here?

Answer (score 0):

According to the question and comments:

1. You must instantiate `AMSenderC` with the same id as for the receiver. In this case, `AM_OSCILLOSCOPE` if you want a message to be processed by the same code. Or another id plus a new implementation of the `Receive` interface.
2. You missed putting payload into `btrpkt`.
3. You must check for `sendbusy` - it is a bug if you try to use the radio stack when it is busy.